# What's a Word for "Very Sick"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for having been very sick, as with the flu or pneumonia? For example, it should fit into the sentence

> A few days after the event, I became ___ and couldn't get out of bed for a few days.

The word needs more intensity than "ill", "unwell", "poorly", "ailing", or "indisposed". It should also not require the word "very". Is there such a word?

Comment: *Critically ill* usually implies being so ill you're in danger of dying. If you just mean you're so ill you can't go to work, perhaps *laid low* or *incapacitated*.

Comment: You used the [single-word-requests] tag. Please check the [tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) and especially the four check points at the end of that. These requests need especial care.

Comment: One could, of course, shorten "critically ill" to "critical", so long as the context was sufficient to identify that as a medical condition (vs, say, an impending nuclear incident).

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Thanks, I didn't know such criteria existed. I edited the question in an attempt to comply.

Comment: You might be able to accomplish your goal by using any of the words you suggest, along with the adverb _so_: _"A few days after the event, I became so ill I couldn't get out of bed for a few days."_ (I realize that's not a word, but at least it gives words like _ill_ and _unwell_ the strength you desire.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I like "incapacitated"! As a mere comment, I can't make it the accepted answer, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Debilitated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/debilitated?s=t) is a possibility:

> The siege of pneumonia debilitated her completely.

For your sentence, bedridden, seems to apply:

> A few days after the event, I became bedridden and couldn't get out of
>   bed for a few days.

There's also [enfeebled](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/enfeebled?s=t):

> Further, as we saw that most of those who went inland to explore fell
>   sick on their return, or even had to turn back on the way, this was a
>   reason to fear that the same might befall those healthy men who might
>   make such an expedition now. And two perils might threaten them there
>   in consquence. First, if they were to fall sick out there in the
>   course of the work, where there is no house nor refuge of any sort
>   from the chief they call Caonabo (who by all accounts is a very bad
>   man and - even more - a very bold one), he seeing us there enfeebled
>   and ill, would be able to undertake that which he would not dare if
>   we were in normal health.

~ Christopher Columbus, *[Columbus on Himself](https://books.google.com/books?id=mev-FxR2MDAC&pg=PA117&dq=enfeebled%20sick&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i3bFVOOpCJHcggT2_oDQDA&ved=0CBwQ6AEwADgU#v=onepage&q=enfeebled%20sick&f=false)*

Answer (score 5):

> What about **[stricken](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stricken)**...like being stricken by a real fever and
>   a sore throat and the chills and. . . you get the idea. Put out of
>   action (by illness).

TFD puts it as-
adj.

> Affected by something *overwhelming*, such as disease, trouble, or
>   painful emotion
>
> - Incapacitated; disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a single word, I think the colloquial  [dogsick](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Dogsick) may fit your context: (TFD)

> - Very unwell, very sick;  [sick as a dog](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/dogsick).

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard that word.  It is confusing at first because the parallel with familiar compounds like *homesick*, *seasick*, *lovesick* would suggest the meaning "sick because of a dog" rather than "sick as a dog".